# « Saoul comme une botte » : de quelle botte s'agit-il ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, québec, origine-ou-raison

> [Saoul](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soul) comme une [botte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/botte). ([Québec](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/saoul-comme-une-botte/))

Certainement un haut degré (*complètement, avec excès*) par analogie ou métaphore. Le [GPFC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossaire_du_parler_fran%C3%A7ais_au_Canada) (1930) mentionne *être en botte*, qui m'est complètement inconnu, pour *être ivre*  ; on dit *bot, botte, boîte* en vieux français pour *outre, tonneau et boisson*, respectivement nous dit-on (GPFC).

---

- De quel sens du mot *botte* s'agit-il ici ?
- Est-ce un glissement de la locution disparue (?) *être en botte* ?
- Pourquoi serait-on en état d'ébriété de cette manière, peut-on étayer
  si c'est ou non relié à l'idée de se *[rouler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouler) par/à terre* ou *sous la table* ?

Answer (score 1):

Une idée qui m’est venue, et donc à ne pas prendre pour argent comptant (ou à prendre avec un grain de sel, en québécois) :

- *« être ivre »* ou *« être saoul »* se dit aussi au Québec *« être chaud »* ;
- *« être chaud comme une botte »* ne s’entend guère *(peut-être à cause de l’ambivalence possible du message : quelqu’un pourrait certes y comprendre* chaud lapin), mais le lien entre la chaleur d’une botte dans l’hiver québécois et celle de l’ivresse serait du moins assez explicite ;
- ***« saoul comme une botte »*** pourrait jouer sur ces deux concepts, sans l’ambiguïté mentionnée : *qqn est saoul <sup>**chaud**</sup> comme une botte <sup>d’hiver est **chaude** pour les pieds</sup>* ;

Seulement voilà ! le mot d’esprit qui peut-être aurait créé cette expression s’est semble-t-il perdu avec les générations...

Comment: tiens je ne connaissais pas `à prendre avec un grain de sel` , c'est l'équivalent québecois de `à prendre avec des pincettes` ?

Comment: @Flying_whale Je ne suis pas entièrement certain de la signification de *«à prendre avec des pincettes»*, mais je peux toujours vous définir *«à prendre avec un grain de sel»*, qui est peut-être un calque de l'anglais *«to take (smthg) with a grain of salt»*: il s'agit d'une invitation à prendre connaissance de ce qui suivra, mais à ne surtout pas y faire aveuglément confiance, parce que ce pourrait être inexact, dans une mesure indéterminée.

Comment: Et un grand merci pour la remarque! Je ne m'étais jamais penché sur cette expression, et votre commentaire m'a fait me poser la question de son origine. C'est très communément utilisé au Québec, mais apparemment pas en Europe. Auriez-vous une expression équivalente à proposer?

Comment: En cherchant un peu, j'ai trouvé *«ne pas prendre (qqch) pour argent comptant»*. Approuveriez-vous?

Comment: oui, "ne pas prendre pour agent comptant" a également ce sens :)

Comment: Merci ! C'est possible qu'on en perde des bouts (de l'expression) en effet... Il y a plein de phénomènes d'« érosion » un peu comme ce que vous décrivez. J'imagine que dans certains cas il y a des ouvrages spécialisés qui traitent de manière plus précise des expressions québécoises. Votre réponse alimente la réflexion. Merci !

Comment: p.s. Merci pour l'échange sur _prendre avec un grain de sel_, j'ai fait une question avec ça !

Comment: @dévastatordeconstuctors Très belle question que vous fîtes! Et fort bien documentée. J'en suis tout tourneboulé et je [la lie ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31731/prendre-avec-un-grain-de-sel-polys%C3%A9mie-exemples-tr%C3%A8s-contemporains-etc) car elle le mérite bien.