# « Prendre avec un grain de sel » : polysémie, exemples très contemporains etc. ?

Tags: sens, locutions, lexique

Dans un article paru il y a 20 ans, on affirme entre autres que :

> Au Canada, l’expression latine [*cum grano salis*] est rarissime. Nous
>   employons volontiers la tournure française [*prendre avec un grain de
>   sel*], le plus souvent avec le sens « anglais » [« avec réserve »,
>   sans nuance d’humour par opposition à  « avec humour », « sans prendre au sérieux ou à la lettre ».].
>
> [ Frèdelin Leroux fils, [*Mots de tête : « prendre avec un grain de sel »*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9Am92FVvGFZo.html) ds. L’Actualité terminologique, vol. 31, no 1, 1998, page 23, sur Termium ]

C'est une locution différente d'*ajouter son [grain](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grain) de [sel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grain_de_sel)*, c'est-à-dire donner son avis, [*se mêler de*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/grain/37775/locution?q=grain%20de%20sel#156428) etc. L'article mentionne que la locution est peu documentée au lexique...

---

1. Peut-on étayer l'emploi de la locution à l'aide de quelques citations/exemples de ces 20 dernières années (dans la presse écrite, la littérature etc.) illustrant les (deux) sens dont il est question, que ce soit au Québec/Canada ou ailleurs ?
2. La locution est-elle davantage documentée aujourd'hui qu'elle ne
   l'était il y a 20 ans (elle n'est pas au DHLF, apparaît
   accidentellement dans une [citation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_prendre_et_en_laisser) sans être documentée au
   Wiktionnaire) ?
3. Trouve-t-on que le sens de [grain](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grain) de sel pour la « pointe d'esprit
   que l'on met dans le langage » (TLFi) se rapproche du sens « avec humour », « sans prendre au sérieux ou à la lettre » ; ce grain de sel là n'est-il jamais utilisé en locution et le cas échéant comment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je trouve des exemples dans les deux sens dans les journaux québécois, mais le sans "avec réserve" tend à prédominer.

Pour moi la seule formule pour laquelle "humour" est le sens primaire est "prendre la vie avec un grain de sel", mais on la rencontre aussi très souvent pour introduire un texte déjanté ou ironique. S'il s'agit de nouvelles, d'annonces etc. je présume toujours le sens "avec des réserves".

### Exemples du sens "réserve"

- Mme Marois a dû prendre avec un grain de sel les assurances de loyale collaboration du chef bloquiste. Elle n'a certainement pas oublié ce qui s'est passé lors de la démission d'André Boisclair. ([*Le Devoir*](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/chroniques/309940/dissiper-le-doute))
- «C'est une bonne nouvelle, mais je prends ça avec un grain de sel»  ([*Le Devoir*](https://www.ledevoir.com/societe/education/339935/nesbitt-pourrait-rester-ouverte))
- Plusieurs éléments de l'étiquetage demeurent très utiles, à commencer par la liste des ingrédients. Ce fameux tableau de valeur nutritive pourtant si en évidence, par contre, mérite d'être pris avec un grain de sel. ([*La Presse*](http://www.lapresse.ca/debats/editoriaux/ariane-krol/201504/08/01-4859315-a-prendre-avec-un-grain-de-sel.php))
- Questionné à ce sujet, le ministre [..] a eu pour réponse qu'il fallait prendre ces statistiques «avec un grain de sel». ([*La Presse*](http://www.lapresse.ca/debats/commentaires-du-jour/201201/09/01-4484123-avec-un-grain-de-sel.php))
- La preuve qu'il faut prendre avec un grain de sel les déclarations tapageuses et les menaces. ([*Le Soleil*](https://www.lesoleil.com/archives/lusure-de-la-guerre-769fb7919ef1060b42eb39e46d707de9))
- Alors qu'il s'apprête à célébrer les 30 ans de la compagnie qu'il a fondée, Michel Bélanger prend la situation avec un grain de sel. ([*Le Soleil*](https://www.lesoleil.com/archives/audiogram30-ans-au-service-de-la-chanson-b7c45dc8d5cc83be18e1791025ac7aaf))
- Ce type de sondage interne des partis politiques est cependant à prendre avec un grain de sel.  ([*Journal de Montréal*](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2018/09/09/quebec-2018---les-grandes-batailles-veronique-hivon-menacee-par-la-caq))

### Exemples du sens "humour"

- Voici mon Top 8 des grandes nouvelles de 2018. À prendre avec un grain de sel, ou deux… ([*Le Soleil*](https://www.lesoleil.com/chroniques/david-goudreault/mon-bilan-de-lannee-2018-22a7c043230eb0cad51234c6350a265e))
- Je m'en voudrais de prendre cela avec un grain de sel. Quand les gens prennent le temps de penser à toi, c'est important de leur faire sentir que c'est apprécié. ([*Le Soleil*](https://www.lesoleil.com/archives/patrick-roy-au-pantheon-des-sports-la-passion-de-gagner-c0ac982fd18fc4209dcb626ad9d0f16b))
- Certains ont grommelé. Alex Harvey a pris le tout avec un grain de sel. «Ça va me faire une p'tite marche», a-t-il philosophé après sa séance d'entraînement. ([*La Presse*](http://www.lapresse.ca/sports/sotchi-2014/ski-et-surf/201402/18/01-4739981-lobsession-dalex-harvey.php))
- À lire avec un grain de sel et un soupçon d’ironie. ([*La Presse+*](http://plus.lapresse.ca/screens/26a7cf9f-cc5b-44bd-bd5f-edbf6b115396__7C___0.html))
- Voici six indices écono-financiers à prendre avec un grain de sel. ([*La Presse+*](http://mi.lapresse.ca/screens/9d2b8b6b-da2d-435b-96b3-0fceddd65ee1__7C___0.html))
- J'ai décidé de prendre la vie avec un grain de sel. Vous savez, pour ne pas être malade, il faut être sain non seulement physiquement, mais aussi psychologiquement et spirituellement. ([*Le Devoir*](https://www.ledevoir.com/culture/cinema/26450/l-entrevue-la-vie-devant-soi))
- Cette façon de raconter les pires drames avec un grain de sel, comme si ça allait de soi. ([*Le Devoir*](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/chroniques/388456/au-coeur-de-la-realite-crasse))
- Amoureux de la nature, cet article, à prendre avec un grain de sel, est pour vous. (*[Journal de Montréal](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2016/04/13/27-personnes-qui-nous-tapent-sur-les-nerfs-en-camping)*)

### Exemple incertain

- L’animatrice prend les discussions entourant son poids «avec un grain de sel» ([*Journal de Montréal*](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2015/09/29/julie-snyder-remercie-son-public))

Comment: Merci ! Vraiment une bonne recherche ! L'exemple incertain bien ça m'a fait penser à prendre à la légère, ou avec un bémol. Prendre la vie avec humour... je me demande si la prendre avec un grain de sel c'est pas les deux sens d'une certaine manière. Merci !